# How to remove html element from string based on child value using php?

Tags: php, html, string, domdocument

There's a html table assigned to a variable $text. (The table can have different number of rows)

What would be the easiest way to get rid of the rows that do not have a value in column 2 (in this example it would be row 2)

Example:

```
$text = <<<EOT
<table style="width: 430px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 199px;"><b>Row 1:</b></b></td>
<td style="width: 413px;">6754</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 199px;"><b>Row 2:</b></td>
<td style="width: 413px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 199px;"><b>Row 3</b></td>
<td style="width: 413px;">7567</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

EOT;
```

Expected result:

```
$text = <<<EOT

<table style="width: 430px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 199px;"><b>Row 1:</b></b></td>
<td style="width: 413px;">6754</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 199px;"><b>Row 3</b></td>
<td style="width: 413px;">7567</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

EOT;
```

Comment: Use [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

Comment: Solved with http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uek-60j

Comment: Also you can use `$xpath->query("//tr[td[2]='']")` to selecting `tr` that second `td` of it is empty

Answer (score 0):

I think using [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) is best way to removing target elements from your html. Using xpath you can select `tr`s that seconds `td` of it is empty.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($text);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$row = $xpath->query("//tr[td[2]='']")->item(0);
$row->parentNode->removeChild($row);
$newText = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Check it in [demo](https://3v4l.org/YTFJ3)